# Telegraf on Kubernetes: Error: Service "telegraf" is invalid: spec.ports: Required value

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, telegraf, telegraf-plugins

**what do I want to do?**

I'm trying to deploy telegraf in my Kubernetes cluster so that I can use Telegraf's **Prometheus** input plugin to read the data (metrics) from a particular URL and write the metrics in a file using telegraf's output **file** plugin.

**what did I do?**

I used the telegraf [helm chart](https://github.com/influxdata/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/telegraf) to deploy telegraf on kubernetes.
I changed the following config changes.
**The original telegraf yaml file:**

```
config:
  agent:
    interval: "10s"
    round_interval: true
    metric_batch_size: 1000
    metric_buffer_limit: 10000
    collection_jitter: "0s"
    flush_interval: "10s"
    flush_jitter: "0s"
    precision: ""
    debug: false
    quiet: false
    logfile: ""
    hostname: "$HOSTNAME"
    omit_hostname: false
  processors:
    - enum:
        mapping:
          field: "status"
          dest: "status_code"
          value_mappings:
            healthy: 1
            problem: 2
            critical: 3
  outputs:
    - influxdb:
        urls:
          - "http://influxdb.monitoring.svc:8086"
        database: "telegraf"
  inputs:
    - statsd:
        service_address: ":8125"
        percentiles:
          - 50
          - 95
          - 99
        metric_separator: "_"
        allowed_pending_messages: 10000
        percentile_limit: 1000
```

**The changes I made to it:**

```
config:
  outputs:
    - file:
        files:
          - "stdout"
          - "metrics.out" 
        data_format: influx  
  inputs:
    - prometheus:
        - urls:
            url: "http://ipaddr:80/metrics"
```

And when I applied the helm chart along with the changes I got
**Error: Service "telegraf" is invalid: spec.ports: Required value** and my deployment failed.

```
chandhana@Azure:~/clouddrive/PromExpose$ helm install telegraf influxdata/telegraf -f telegraf-values.yaml
Error: Service "telegraf" is invalid: spec.ports: Required value
```

Please do help me if I'm making any mistakes on the changed YAML configuration since I didn't find any resource for yaml format of telegraf's input and output plugin.
Additional link for reference:
[telegraf .conf file](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/etc/telegraf.conf)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to enable metrics in [values.yaml](https://github.com/influxdata/helm-charts/blob/master/charts/telegraf/values.yaml#L170-L173), its disabled by default.
Correct part is

```
metrics:
  health:
    enabled: true
  collect_memstats: false
```

Change your `telegraf-values.yaml` to

```
config:
  agent:
    interval: "10s"
    round_interval: true
    metric_batch_size: 1000
    metric_buffer_limit: 10000
    collection_jitter: "0s"
    flush_interval: "10s"
    flush_jitter: "0s"
    precision: ""
    debug: false
    quiet: false
    logfile: ""
    hostname: "$HOSTNAME"
    omit_hostname: false
  processors:
    - enum:
        mapping:
          field: "status"
          dest: "status_code"
          value_mappings:
            healthy: 1
            problem: 2
            critical: 3
  outputs:
    - file:
        files:
          - "stdout"
          - "metrics.out" 
        data_format: influx 
  inputs:
    - prometheus:
        - urls:
            url: "http://ipaddr:80/metrics"

metrics:
  health:
    enabled: true
  collect_memstats: false
```

Result:

```
helm install telegraf influxdata/telegraf -f values.yaml
NAME: telegraf
LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Jun 25 10:35:05 2021
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
To open a shell session in the container running Telegraf run the following:

  kubectl exec -i -t --namespace default $(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l app.kubernetes.io/name=telegraf -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') /bin/sh

To view the logs for a Telegraf pod, run the following:

  kubectl logs -f --namespace default $(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l app.kubernetes.io/name=telegraf -o jsonpath='{ .items[0].metadata.name }')
```

Comment: This worked for me when encountering the same error. Note that the metrics key belongs in the top-level of the values, not under `config` (I only mention this to avoid potential confusion, since the overall chart documentation is not very clear.)